# Rails Tutorial: Short-Circuit Evaluation in section 8.4.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm going in circles with a bit of code in section 8.4.4 ("Two Subtle Bugs") in the 3rd edition of Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial. (Link to this section of the text: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-two_subtle_bugs[1])

Specifically I'm confused about the following text/code:

> "The second subtlety is that a user could be logged in (and
>   remembered) in multiple browsers, such as Chrome and Firefox, which
>   causes a problem if the user logs out in one browser but not the
>   other. For example, suppose that the user logs out in Firefox, thereby
>   setting the remember digest to nil (via user.forget in Listing 8.38).
>   This would still work in Firefox, because the log_out method in
>   Listing 8.39 deletes the user’s id, so the user variable would be nil
>   in the current_user method:

```
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

> As a result, the expression
>
> `user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])`
>
> returns false due to short-circuit evaluation."

For this question, let's stick with Firefox and not worry about the second browser bug. Hartl seems to be saying the following:

1. The log_out method sets the remember digest to nil in the database.
2. The log_out method deletes the user_id stored in both the session
   and cookie.
3. A subsequent call to the current_user method from within the same browser would not raise  an error because "the user variable would be nil in the current_user method." This would cause short-circuiting of the expression `user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])`.

My questions is how this could ever happen. If the log_out method works as stated, shouldn't the line `elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])` be false on subsequent calls? The elsif block wouldn't run and  the user variable would never be set. In fact both conditionals in the current_user method would be false and the method would return nil. There would be no short-circuiting based on the user variable.

Can the short-circuit evaluation that he describes take place?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the short-circuit does not occur since

> elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])

does not run and the user variable would never be set **IN FIREFOX.**, since the cookie is delted in Sessions Helper:

```
# Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
```

However, that doesn't change Hartl's main point that the user was also logged in via **Chrome**, which is where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Hartl has recently edited that section of the book (as of early March 2015), and now the current way he describes it doesn't seem to have this error.